# Why won't this regular expression match anything in VSCode search & replace?

Tags: css, regex, visual-studio-code, html-email

I'm using the VSCode
[image]

Screenshot to demonstrate the search options I have selected:
[image]

And here is the expression I'm trying to use.  It works in other places, such as regexr.com, but not in VSCode...

```
font\-size\:\s{0,1}\d{2,2}px\;\s{0,1}
```

Here is the HTML:

https://codepen.io/JashoowellPadderssonn/pen/WNbVVEq

I have also tried disabling all extensions which did not work.  Here are my VSCode settings:

https://gist.github.com/CrocodileInAWhileAlligatorLater/409f0d9d179955ff80419a8a4506a09d

Comment: I have 6 matches using the text you linked to and your regex. VSCode 1.38.1

Comment: That is strange.  I wonder what could be causing my search and replace to not work?  I have all extensions disabled currently...  I will add my VSCode settings now at the end of the post.

Comment: Ok, v.1.41 exposes a different behavior. The fix is `font-size:\s{0,1}\d{2}px;\s{0,1}` or `font-size:\s?\d{2}px;\s?`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should only escape the characters that need to be escaped.

Use

```
font-size:\s?\d{2}px;\s?
```

Note the `-` (here), `:` and `;` are not special and thus MUST NOT be escaped.

The reason for it is that the regex is [now](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/61746#issuecomment-512616065) [compiled](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/250c58e66d4f79c86d85e9c6a03b5e432faf43b3#diff-471f768028ced3be87d31af1ace2276b) with the `u` modifier enabling Unicode property classes to work (e.g. `\p{L}` matches any Unicode letter). Here is a [VSCode Github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/61746), *Consider searching with JS regexes in unicode mode*. It was closed on September 3, 2019 and verified on October 3, 2019.

The side effect is that there are ***more strict requirements to escaping***.

*Outside of character classes, `[...]`*, the following chars must be escaped: `.`, `^`, `$`, `*`, `+`, `?`, `(`, `)`, `[`, `{` (you may leave it unescaped in the majority  of cases, however, if you need to find `{` followed with a number and then `}` escaping becomes required, cf. `/a\{3}/` (matches `a{3}`) != `/a{3}/` - matches three `a`s), `\` и `|`.

*Inside character classes*, these chars must ALWAYS be escaped: `]` and `\`. The  `-` must be escaped if it is not located at the beginning or end of the character class (`[-0-9_]` = `[0-9_-]` = `[_\-0-9]`), and `^` must be escaped when at the character class start denoting a literal `^` (`[^0]` (matches any char other than `0`) != `[\^0]` (matches `^` or `0`)). See [What special characters must be escaped in regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078).

Comment: This is excellent work.  I've verified that it's working using a variety of other expressions.  Kudos.  I must admit, I am a bit confused in that they say it's "more strict" because this seems a bit easier now that I know about Unicode properties, but I can picture what they mean.